# How to fix this Indexing error when trying to use EAST OpenCV for Text recognition?

Tags: python, opencv

How to fix this Indexing error when trying to use EAST OpenCV for Text Recognition? There is some issue with the for loop but I am not able to fix it. Any help will be much apprecited!

````
confThreshold = 0.5
nmsThreshold = 0.3
[boxes, confidences] = decode(scores, geometry, confThreshold)
indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxesRotated(boxes, confidences, confThreshold, nmsThreshold)



height_ = frame.shape[0]
width_ = frame.shape[1]
rW = width_ / float(inpWidth)
rH = height_ / float(inpHeight)

for i in indices:
    # get 4 corners of the rotated rect
    vertices = cv2.boxPoints(boxes[i[0]])
    # scale the bounding box coordinates based on the respective ratios
    for j in range(4):
        vertices[j][0] *= rW
        vertices[j][1] *= rH
    for j in range(4):
        p1 = (vertices[j][0], vertices[j][1])
        p2 = (vertices[(j + 1) % 4][0], vertices[(j + 1) % 4][1])
        cv2.line(frame, p1, p2, (0, 255, 0), 3)

# To save the image:
cv2.imwrite("annotated_image.jpg", frame)

```

Error:IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [80], in <module>
      4 rH = height_ / float(inpHeight)
      6 for i in indices:
      7     # get 4 corners of the rotated rect
----> 8     vertices = cv2.boxPoints(boxes[i[0]])
      9     # scale the bounding box coordinates based on the respective ratios
     10     for j in range(4):

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
````

I changed the iterator from i[0] to i, but now this error pops up:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [88], in <module>
     14         p1 = (vertices[j][0], vertices[j][1])
     15         p2 = (vertices[(j + 1) % 4][0], vertices[(j + 1) % 4][1])
---> 16         cv2.line(frame, p1, p2, (0, 255, 0), 3)
     18 # To save the image:
     19 cv2.imwrite("annotated_image.jpg", frame)

error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'line'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
```

Comment: looks like a bug in the sample. indices has 1d shape so it should be simply `i` not `i[0]`. maybe it's even a bug in the python wrappers, and the handling of `std::vector` has changed (it *used  to be* a 2d numpy array, but clearly it isnt so here !). alarming find !

Comment: @berak I changed the iterator from i[0] to i. But this error pops up. Could you explain why?  I have updated the original post

Comment: p1 and p2 must be all *integer* (you probably have some floats in there) wrap it like: `p1 = (int(vertices[j][0]), int(vertices[j][1]))` etc

Comment: Thanks @berak, it is working fine now!

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3eeec4faae0c8b020d0efd30a51c1e97a0f444a5/samples/dnn/text_detection.py#L225-L226